# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "comments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate data from multiple collection.

```
posts.find({})
      .populate({ path: 'comments',
           populate: {path:'users',model:'User'} 
              }).sort('_id').limit(10)
     .exec(function (err, Post) {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err)
         }
         else{

         res.write(JSON.stringify(Post),null,4);
         res.end();
         }
     });

 };
```

but I get this error.

**Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "comments**

**That's my Posts Schema:-**

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user_id: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }],

  categories_id:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' }],

  text: String,

  description:String,

  imgpath: String,

  audio_path: String,

  video_path: String,

  question_text: String, 

  created_at: {type:Number, default: new Date().getTime()},

  comments:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'comments' }],

  updated_at:{type:Number, default: new Date().getTime()}
})
```

**Comment Schema**

```
var CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  post_id: String,

  users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }],

  comment_text: String,

  image_path: String,

  video_path: String,

  updated_at: {type:Number, default: new Date().getTime()}
});
```

**and one more thing i want to know ,how can we handle populate if data not exist in that collection?**

Comment: show your schema code as well

Comment: show comments schema please.